# ID from axios.delete request not making it to req.body to then delete from mySQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I'm using Axios to handle my requests on my application. I have confirmed via PostMan that my DELETE request is working, now I'm writing the code for the front end and I'm getting a 404 error on my click event.

I've isolated the issue to the axios.delete request, for some reason when the onClick event is triggered it's not passing the information to the req.body.

I've confirmed that "movie" in the deleteMovie method is the id I want brought up from the passed down prop.

App.jsx :

```
  deleteMovie(movie) {
    axios.delete('/movies', { data: { id: movie } }) // movie = ID of the movie entry in mySQL
    .then(res => {this.setState({
      movies: this.state.movies
    })})
    .catch(err => {console.log(err)})
  }
```

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const movies = require('./controllers/movies.js');
const db = require('./db/connection.js');
const app = express();

const publicDirectory = path.join(__dirname, '../client/dist');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(publicDirectory));

app.get('/movies', movies.get);
app.post('/movies', movies.post);

app.delete('/movies', movies.delete);

app.listen(3000);
```

controller file:

```
module.exports = {
  delete: (req, res) => {

    console.log('req.body console log:', req.body); // This is currently returning: {} Info from front end never makes it here

    const movie = req.body.id;
    const query = `DELETE FROM movieList WHERE id = ${movie}`;

    model.deleteMovie(query, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(404);
        res.end();
      } else {
        res.sendStatus(201);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

model file:

```
module.exports.deleteMovie = (query, callback) => {
  db.connection.query(query, err => {
    return err ? callback(err) : callback(null);
  })
}
```

Comment: Look in the network tab of the Chrome debugger and look at the EXACT request that `axios.delete()` is sending.  You want to determine if the `{id: movie}` is in the body of the delete request or not and if the request is tagged as application/json and if the data is indeed in the JSON format.  If it is, then the problem is over on the Express side.  If it is not there, then the problem is in the axios call.  Narrow the problem down so you know where to focus further effort and debugging.

Comment: Can't really help very effectively if you just post and disappear.  One sides conversations don't work very well.  Stackoverflow is not like some online forum where you post and come back the next day to check for answers.  You get the best help when you check back frequently after posting so you can engage with those who are trying to help.

Comment: @jfriend00 Hey, sorry I posted that I confirmed I saw 'application/json' in the network tab of Chrome. I removed it when something came to mind and I wanted to confirm before reposting. I ended up solving this by changing my DELETE request to a different format, as such:

  deleteMovie(movie) {
    axios({
      method: 'delete',
      url: '/movies',
      header: 'application/json',
      data: {
        id: movie
      }
    })
}

Can you help me understand why this format works? Thank you.

Comment: Well, the way to figure out why would have been to thoroughly  debug your original axios call and see what was missing from it and/or what is different from the request the new code is sending.  That's how you would find out.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it's a bug in axios itself, try bumping to 0.21 - see here for the fix https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/3282

Answer (score 0):

From reading your code, it might be that your are wrapping your movie id in an object. like this: `{data: {id: movie};`

This might cause some problems when you try to use this data from in your express server in the request object. Your are trying to use that id like this: `const movie = req.body.id;` But it seems like you should do like this: `const movie = req.body.data.id;` since you wrap the id in another object. This is usually what you do while sending data from an API, however not that common from the frondend.
Try this instead, to just set the data parameter as an anonymous object with id: movie. Might just be that small problem, from where you make the delete req.

```
deleteMovie(movie) {
    axios.delete('/movies', { id: movie }) // movie = ID of the movie entry in mySQL
    .then(res => {this.setState({
      movies: this.state.movies
    })})
    .catch(err => {console.log(err)})
  }
```